# Pop up or sound after completion of any running process in terminal (Linux)

Tags: linux, terminal, linux-kernel, gnome-terminal

I want to write a program for having a pop up or sound after completion of any running process in terminals of any Linux distributions. 
Many times I run some command in the terminal and leave it to complete the process but then I have to keep checking that whether it has been completed or not. Any suggestions on how to get started with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using `notify-send`, which is available on most linux desktop environments:

```
yourCommand; notify-send "Completed !:0" "Exit status: $?"
```

Another tool for such things is `zenity`:

```
yourCommand; zenity --info --text "Command !:0 completed with exit code $?"
```

Both tools are either already installed on your system or easily installable with the package manager. You might want to wrap the above snippets into an `alias` or into a custom script that you place somewhere in your `$PATH`.